# How put a icon on CameraSource?

Tags: java, android

I need add an icon to take pictures on my cameraSource but I'm using a custom library (developed by a third person). My icon needs to be inside cameraSourcePreview tag.

```
private Context mContext;
    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private boolean mStartRequested;
    private boolean mSurfaceAvailable;
    private CameraSource mCameraSource;

    private GraphicOverlay mOverlay;

    public CameraSourcePreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        mStartRequested = false;
        mSurfaceAvailable = false;

        mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
        mSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceCallback());
        addView(mSurfaceView);
    }
```

I tried put in my xml but it doesn't works.

My xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/topLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">

    <com.example.aveek.barcodescanner.ui.CameraSourcePreview
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
            android:id="@+id/qr_image"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:keepScreenOn="true" />

        <com.example.aveek.barcodescanner.ui.GraphicOverlay
            android:id="@+id/graphicOverlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </com.example.aveek.barcodescanner.ui.CameraSourcePreview>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```

I have this ugly design:

[image]

How I can do this? I tried change SuurfaceView to FrameLayout too.

Comment: Instead of LinearLayout use a FrameLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - change the parent view from LinearLayout to RelativeLayout so that you could put a View (button in your case) on the the TOP of other view(CameraSourcePreview).

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/topLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">

    <com.example.aveek.barcodescanner.ui.CameraSourcePreview
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
            android:id="@+id/qr_image"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:keepScreenOn="true" />

        <com.example.aveek.barcodescanner.ui.GraphicOverlay
            android:id="@+id/graphicOverlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </com.example.aveek.barcodescanner.ui.CameraSourcePreview>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```